# Where can I find pre trained word embeddings (English) in word2vec format of 50 dimensions?

Tags: word2vec, word-embedding, pre-trained-model

Preferably it should be a txt file than a binary file. All of the pre-trained word embeddings I found where of 300+ dimensions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
Download this file which in GloVe format and convert it to word2vec format using this script: https://github.com/jroakes/glove-to-word2vec

Answer (score 0):

It is plausibly the case that any 50 dimensions of a 300-dimensional model are still useful. So you could conceivably take a 300-dimensional set, in text, and patch the file to specify 50-dimensions and discard the last 250 dimensions of each line.